# How to customize the toolbar in Flask-MDEditor

Tags: python, flask, markdown, editor.md

I'm using the flask-mdeditor extension and I'd like to customize the toolbar to eliminate some functions. I've read the documentation, but I'm not sure where/when/how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can find markdown.html in the path of templates. The default configuration has been defined in this file, you can try to modify the file to achieve your idea.

Reference from [custom-toolbar description](http://editor.md.ipandao.com/examples/custom-toolbar.html)

PS: I'm the author, and would welcome a pull request.